# How get I obtain an item field from a Sitecore MVC view helper?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

Now in the helper method I go the current item being passed. But I cannot find a method to get the value of a field. The item class is  Sitecore.Data.Items.Item

Comment: Did you try item.Fields["..."]?  (with the field name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = ...;
var f  = item["field name"];
var f1 = item[0];//field id
var f2 = item[new ID("field id")];
var f3 = item.Fields["field name"];
var f4 = item.Fields[0];//field index
var f5 = item.Fields[new ID("field id")];
```